# Showing amount with currency

Tags: finance, bank

what is the best way to show currency with amount in financial applications ??

like,

USD 20.00 || Rs. 100.00 || EUR 50.00
or

20.00 USD || 10.00 Rs. || EUR 50.00
or

USD - 20.00 || Rs. - 10.00 || EUR - 50.00

or something else ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style guide used by the institutions of the European Union includes rules [for expressing monetary units](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm). The most important ones:

- Use the written name ('an amount in euros') when a monetary unit is
  referred to generally but an amount is not included
- ISO code ‘EUR’ followed by a fixed space and the amount in figures in written text (compulsory in legal texts). (In English,
  Irish, Latvian and Maltese. In all other official EU languages the
  order is reversed: 250 EUR).
- The euro sign € is primarily used in graphics. However, its use is also permitted in popular works and promotional publications (e.g.
  sales catalogues). No space after the euro sign: €35.

My personal preference would be €1.234.567,89 for most texts (that feels most natural and familiar) and 1.234.567,89 EUR for legal/formal documents (or EUR 1.234.567,89 when written in English).

For more details: [Complete list of currency formats.](http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct way to show currency required that you should remain consistent with one type: `go with either USD 20.00 or 20.00 USD` and so on..

However i would not recommend to **not** to go with

```
USD - 20.00 || Rs. - 10.00 || EUR - 50.00
```

as this will create conflict between negative and positive currency numbers.

Hope this helps.